# Angular: JSONArray - Add two columns in table

Tags: json, angular

I have this JSON-Array

```
Array(8)
0: (3) ["Test", "1", "222"]
1: (3) ["Test", "2", "333"]
2: (3) ["Test", "3", "444"]
3: (3) ["Test", "4", "555"]
4: (3) ["Test", "5", "666"]
5: (3) ["Test", "6", "777"]
6: (3) ["Test", "7", "888"]
```

An i would like to change this array into looking like this, adding the first two columns together:

```
Array(8)
0: (2) ["Test1", "222"]
1: (2) ["Test2", "333"]
2: (2) ["Test3", "444"]
3: (2) ["Test4", "555"]
4: (2) ["Test5", "666"]
5: (2) ["Test6", "777"]
6: (2) ["Test7", "888"]
```

For this I tried:

```
Array.forEach(data =>{
    data[0] + data[1] = data[0]
}
```

but it didnt work.

What would be a simple way to do this within the code?

Comment: `const newTable = myTable.map(v => ([v[0] + v[1], v[2]]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const foo = [
  ["Test", "1", "222"],
  ["Test", "2", "333"],
  ["Test", "3", "444"],
  ["Test", "4", "555"],
  ["Test", "5", "666"],
  ["Test", "6", "777"],
  ["Test", "7", "888"],
]


const transformed = foo.map(item => ([item[0] + item[1], item[2]]))
```

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vchfzjum/).